# C# XNA Random tile engine

Tags: c#, random, xna, tile, tile-engine

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch theSpriteBatch)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(0); y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(1); x++) {
                theSpriteBatch.Draw(tile[rand.Next(0,3)], new Rectangle(x*tileWidth,y*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight), 
                    Color.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I do this it just flickers the tiles and constantly redraws them. What do I do to get the random effect with it only drawing once? Is there a way I could click on these tiles with the mouse and have them change? Also, is there a way to make one tile more prevalent than the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking to only randomly generate the tiles **one time** and then draw THAT random sequence **every time**. Remember, `Draw` in XNA runs every "frame", which is generally way more than once per second!

Copy your current loops over to a new area: your map loading. Also add a 2D data structure (array or whatever) to store the results of your tile generation. I'm calling my sample 2D integer array `tileNums`. Now, keep the loops as they are now but change the innards to store the results instead of draw:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(0); y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(1); x++) {
            tileNums[x, y] = rand.Next(0,3);
        }
    }
```

Now just change the innards of your current `Draw` loop to no longer generate randomly and instead to take from this data:

```
    //Random object no longer needed
    for(int y = 0; y < map.GetLength(0); y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < map.GetLength(1); x++) {
            theSpriteBatch.Draw(tile[tileNums[x, y]], new Rectangle(x*tileWidth,y*tileHeight,tileWidth,tileHeight), 
                Color.White);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know draw ran every frame, but I figured that was the problem when I seen it flickering. I just wasn't sure how to handle getting the random but I got it now. One problem though I get index out of bounds with the tileNums array. I create the array like this int[,] tileNums = new int[0,3]; right?

Comment: Nope, those are the sizes of each dimension. This structure should be the exact same size as your map, so I would do `new int[map.GetLength(1), map.GetLength(0)];` (since I did it `x, y`, of course you could do `y, x` and reverse them)

Comment: Ahhh! Ok that makes perfect sense now that I think about it :p. Thanks a ton for helping me out