# XNA randomized tile/terrain generation tutorials?

Tags: xna, terrain

I've been trying to find a good tutorial on how to program randomized tile generation (2D). However it seems that i cannot find any proper tutorials on that.

Is there any books and/or websites with proper tutorials on how to program it and the math behind it?

I know this is not a programming question per se however it is programming related, so hopefully someone can help me out with a link or two.

Comment: what tutorials did you look at, and why did you think they weren't proper ?

Comment: I havent really found any tutorials that touch the subject "Randomized terrain generation". Other then just randomizing an array. Which is not proper terrain generation in my eyes, since theres no way to control the generation to make sure roads connect and so on.

Comment: You should ask questions like this on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. Also duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18735/how-can-i-create-a-random-world-in-a-tile-engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A good [introduction](https://web.archive.org/web/20200226000042/http://www.riemers.net:80/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_basics.php) to random terrains
- Very basic [2D terrain](https://web.archive.org/web/20191219163615/http://www.riemers.net:80/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Random_terrain.php) tutorial
- And .[this](https://web.archive.org/web/20081203222009/http://jrepp.com/2007/07/19/xna-random-terrain-generation-sample-code/) one i found a little more confusing, but it has a lot
  of example [code](https://web.archive.org/web/20090108035545/http://jrepp.com/code/Terrain.cs).

But remember if you use other people's code give them credit :) hope these help.

Comment: I was gonna suggest Riemers XNA Tutorial, but then I checked out your links. ;)

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately those arent using tiles. Though they seem quite interesting i will give them a look.

Comment: Right, I've read through your suggestions Lyuben, unfortunately i cant use them, they arent tilebased (Other then the last one, and thats really just randomizing the terrain, not making proper terrain based on randomized generation (I.e if there was beach terrain and forest terrain, it would be able to accidentally put beach terrain and forest terrain together.))

Comment: @Etarnalazure please look at this [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460807/c-sharp-xna-random-tile-engine) question, it might be of some value for you as they are talking about generating diffrent tiles, and then re-drawing them.